# Algorithm to build streets in a city with minimum cost?

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, shortest-path

**Question details:**
Rashof is the mayor of EMLand. EMLand consists of intersections and streets. There is exactly one path from each intersection to any of the other intersections. Intersections are denoted by positive intergers 1...n.
A construction company has offered Rashof to rebuild all streets of the EMLand, but Rashof can choose `at most k of them to be rebuilt.` The Construction company has offered a new length for each street which means after the street is rebuilt the length of the street changes.
Now Rashof as the mayor of the city must choose wisely so as to minimize sum of lengths of paths between all pairs of intersections.
Help Rashof!

Algorithm:
**Notations**:  old edge length is `L` , new length is `L'` and  set of edges `E` .

1. Count(`C`) number of `edges(E')` whose length is going to decrease i.e. L' < L
2. If `C` is less than or equal to `K` then 
           take all edges(E') into account i.e. Update length of all such edges in E
3. Else 
           1 . Sort all edges(E') based on (L'- L) in ascending order 
           2 . Sort those edges(E'' ⊆ E') whose (L'-L) is same based on L' in descending order 
           3.hoose 1st  K edges(E''' ⊆ E') and update length of all such edges in E
4. Construct Graph G with Edge E and length L
5. Apply any shortest distance algorithm or DFS to find distance b/w each pair of node .

Implementation of above algorithm using priority queue and Dijkstra algorithm.

```
    #include <bits/stdc++.h>
    using namespace std;
    typedef pair<int,int> pii;
    struct s{
    int x;
    int y;
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    };
    const int MAX = 100000;
    const long long INF = 100000000000000000;
    vector< pii > G[MAX];
    long long d[MAX];
    void dijkstra(long long start) {
        int u, v, i, c, w;
        priority_queue< pii, vector< pii >, greater< pii > > Q;
        for(i=0;i<MAX;i++){
            d[i]=INF;
        }
        Q.push(pii(0, start));
        d[start] = 0;
        while(!Q.empty()) {
            u = Q.top().second; // node
            c = Q.top().first; // node cost so far
            Q.pop(); // remove the top item.
            if(d[u] < c) continue;
            for(i = 0; i < G[u].size(); i++) {
                v = G[u][i].first; // node
                w = G[u][i].second; // edge weight
                if(d[v] > d[u] + w) {
                    d[v] = d[u] + w;
                    //cout<<d[v];
                    Q.push(pii(d[v], v));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    bool func(const s s1,const s s2) { return (s1.c < s2.c); }
    bool func2(const s s1,const s s2) { return (s1.b < s2.b); }
    int main() {
        long long n, e, u, V, w,x,y,a,b,t,i,j,k,res,z=2;
        s S;
        vector<s> v;
        map<pair<int,int>,int> m;
        map<pair<int,int>,int>::iterator it;
        cin>>t;
        while(t--){
            cin>>n>>k;
            for(i = 1; i <= n; i++) G[i].clear();
            v.clear();
            m.clear();
            for(i=1;i<n;i++){
                cin>>x>>y>>a>>b;
                if(b<a){
                    S.x = x;
                    S.y =y;
                    S.a=a;
                    S.b=b;
                    S.c=b-a;
                    v.push_back(S);
                }
                m[make_pair(x,y)]=a;
            }
            if(v.size()<=k){
                for(i=0;i<v.size();i++){
                     m[make_pair(v[i].x,v[i].y)]=v[i].b;
                }
                it = m.begin();
                for(;it!=m.end();++it){
                    u = it->first.first;
                    V = it->first.second;
                    w = it->second;
                    G[u].push_back(pii(V, w));
                    G[V].push_back(pii(u, w));
                }
                res = 0;
                for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
                    dijkstra(i);
                    for(j= 1; j <= n; j++) {
                        if(i == j) continue;
                        if(d[j] >= INF) ;
                        else res+=d[j];
                    }
                }
                cout<<res/z<<"\n";
            }
            else{
                sort(v.begin(),v.end(),func);
                for(i=0;i<v.size();i++){
                    j = i;
                    while(v[i].c==v[j].c&&j<v.size())j++;
                    sort(v.begin()+i,v.begin()+j,func2);
                    i=j;
                }
                for(i=0;i<k;i++){
                     m[make_pair(v[i].x,v[i].y)]=v[i].b;
                }
                it = m.begin();
                for(;it!=m.end();++it){
                    u = it->first.first;
                    V = it->first.second;
                    w = it->second;
                    G[u].push_back(pii(V, w));
                    G[V].push_back(pii(u, w));
                }
                res = 0;
                for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
                    dijkstra(i);
                    for(j= 1; j <= n; j++) {
                        if(i == j) continue;
                        if(d[j] >= INF) ;
                        else res+=d[j];
                    }
                }
                cout<<res/z<<"\n";
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

`It passes only 2 test cases out of 9 test cases .` Why this algorithm didn't work ?
or What are the modification should be done in this algorithm to get accepted ?
**Reference:**
[Rashof, Mayor of EMLand](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/morgan-stanley/challenges/rashof-mayor-of-emland)

Comment: "There is exactly one path from each intersection to any of the other intersections." edit: my bad, this implies chain/star and no cycles

Comment: @softwarenewbie7331 no, it just means the graph is a tree.

Comment: No every thing is not in a line . take an example `{2 1 2 3}
{2 3 4 1}
{2 4 3 1}` were 1st value denotes starting vertex , 2nd neighbour ,3rd length b/w them and 4th new length b/w them .

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark It produces wrong o/p i.e. it pass just 2 test case out of 9 test case . What are the modification should be done to get accepted or pass all test case .

Comment: @Henry you are correct. sonu um i can't read your hacky code, sorry, just provided an alternative algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that this is a tree, so, each edge connects **two connected components**.

Assume that we have edge connect between two connected components A and B, which contains n and m numbers of intersections, so, by decreasing the edge by x unit, we will decrease the total distance by `n*m*x`.

```
A---B---C----E
    |   |
    |   |
D----   -----F
```

Look at the graph above, edge between B and C connect two connected components, (A,B,D) and (C,E,F), decreasing the weight of this edge will decrease the distance between (A,B,D) and (C,E,F)

So, the algorithm is to select k edges, which has the largest `n*m*x` (if `x` is positive).

Comment: Off course running Dijkstra is meaning less but not wrong since it can also find distance b/w each pair of node even though their is only one path . So better way to use DFS.

Comment: @hk6279 x is the maximum weight we can decrease from and edge (so if the edge is 10, we can make it 1, so x is 9), a and b is number of vertices. In above example, for (A,B,D) and (C,E,F) a is 3 and b is 3

Comment: @sonukumar because from (A,B,D) to (C,E,F), we need to go through edge B-C, so decrease this will make all costs from A -> C,E,F... decrease

Comment: Would it be better to use defined variable `n` and `m` instead of undefined variable `a` and `b`?

Comment: @sonukumar hmm, Dijkstra is not necessary, but not wrong, you are right :) The wrong path is you select the edge by x, and this is not enough, as pointed out in my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Traverse the tree/graph (eg nonrecursive DFS starting from any node) and count the number of times each edge is used (number of nodes on one side * number of nodes on the other side)
2. For each possible rebuild multiply delta by count
3. Sort
4. Profit

Comment: Can you provide some more details about your algorithm ?

Comment: huh. just run DFS and count the nodes on either side of each edge. I'm not sure if there's any details im missing.

Comment: Hmm, this is similar to mine :) , but I don't understand which is delta by count? I think you are missing one element, which is the weight of the edge :)

Comment: @PhamTrung delta is the change in cost of an edge when you rebuild. count is the number of times an edge occurs in the set of paths (calculated in step 1). Edit: edge weights, path costs, actual paths are redundant for this algo.

Comment: @softwarenewbie7331 Thanks, nice answer :) It's nice to mention DFS at the first path.